# Search in combobox with pagination extjs

Tags: extjs, combobox

Hello i'm trying to do search in combobox.It's working but search only in current page i'm using pagination with search too i need to search in all pages not current page only

Any suggestion

---

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    fieldLabel: 'Organization Id',
    name: 'company_id',
    displayField:'name_en',
    valueField:'id',
    store: Ext.create('UserApp.store.PicklistList', {
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: ['id', 'name_en', 'name_se'],
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            api: {
                read:'picklist/listitems'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'root',
                successProperty: 'success'
            },
            extraParams:{
                table :'table_name'
            }
        }
    }),
    editable: true,
    autoSelect: false,
    selectOnFocus:true,
    typeAhead:true,
    minChars:2,
    queryMode: 'local',
    mode: 'local',
    pageSize: 25,
    width:370,
    allowOnlyWhitespace: false,
    regex: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/, // avoid to empty data only
})
```

Comment: It would be much easier to diagnose if you could post your code.  Are you using a remote or local store?

Comment: code added i'm using remote store and querymode for it it's local

Comment: How is `this.store` defined?

Comment: at initComponent for example 

initComponent: function(){
this.store = Ext.create('App.store.CountriesStore');
}

Comment: No, I mean can you post the full definition of your store?

Comment: I don't understand how this could be doing what you say it is doing; `pageSize` only applies when `queryMode: remote`.  See the docs for this here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-pageSize

Comment: it's working with in queryModel:'local' however i'm change it now for queryMode:'remote' but still not working and also search not working correctly

Comment: You will have to modify your server to handle a remote search.  The proxy will send the typed string to your server as whatever you have defined your `filterParam` (see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-filterParam), and you can use that to filter the store and send back only the filtered records.

Answer (score 0):

1. your store needs to be setup for [pagination](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize)
2. your server needs to handle pagination correctly based on the parameters received from the store's proxy. The proxy will send up querystring parameters like `?page=1&start=0&limit=25`, and your server needs to return only 25 (for example) records and a total parameter.

   `{"total":101,"data":[{model data}, {model data}, ...]}`
3. despite the documentation, the pageSize property in combobox is actually a boolean, turning pagination on if 1 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using combobox with queryMode : 'remote' and doing a search withing combobox for matches. I'm doing a 'contains' search - meaning it looks for matches anywhere in the result string not just beginning and also it searches for values not only in current page but in the entire resultset. I'm using extjs 4.0.7 and i achived it by overriding doQuery method.

`doQuery: function(queryString, forceAll) {
        this.expand();
        this.store.clearFilter(!forceAll);

```
    if(this.queryMode == 'remote') {
        this.store.load({
            params: this.getParams(queryString)
        });
    }
    if (!forceAll) {
        this.store.filter(this.displayField, new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(queryString), 'i'));
    }
}`
```