# Pagination in Combobox in Dojo 1.4

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, pagination

I am using Dojo 1.4. I want server side pagination in Combobox. I set `PageSize=10` to Combobox. But now I want to handle the event fire of `"More Options"` and `"Previous Options"`. I am using `ItemFileReadStore`. I tried

```
onPage="nextAccountList" request="nextAccountList" 
fetch="nextAccountList" serverQuery = "nextAccountList" querystring ="nextAccountList"
```

Can anyone help me to handle this event?

Comment: and have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318256/search-in-combobox-with-pagination-extjs

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am using DOJO. My server side code able to do pagination.

Comment: Why don't you use dojo 1.9 and an enhancedGrid to display your Data? There's a way to implement the plugin called "pagination" and this one does exactly what you want to do. Have a look: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Pagination.html#dojox-grid-enhancedgrid-plugins-pagination

Comment: The question is clearly regarding a Dijit ComboBox, which is not nearly a grid component.  Throwing myriad grid components at the problem is not a solution.

Comment: And once again learned more about dojo. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "more options" and "previous options" entries in Dijit's ComboBox and FilteringSelect automatically operate based on the paging API of the `dojo/data` API.  However, `dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore` operates completely in-memory - if provided an `href`, it will send one request to the server to grab all items up-front, then performs all filtering/sorting/paging on the client side.

If you want to take advantage of server-side paging, you will need to use a different store implementation which fires a server request for each `fetch` call, with the appropriate parameters.  There are a couple of implementations which might be of use to you in `dojox/data`, specifically `dojox/data/QueryReadStore` (which expects output similar to `ItemFileReadStore`) and `dojox/data/JsonRestStore` (which expects a RESTful interface, as described in http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/rest.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I tried dojox.data.QueryReadStore, but my request is having 3 params here {start=[Ljava.lang.String;@d09b953f
accountNumber=[Ljava.lang.String;@67f0b8f3
count=[Ljava.lang.String;@4738bc1b}. Here accountNumber is {searchAttr="accountNumber"}. I want to customize request and request params. What is the event that i can handle for this?

Comment: `accountNumber` is originating from the `searchAttr` setting of your ComboBox as you said. Unfortunately `start` and `count` (representing what offset to start at and how many items to return) are hard-coded - you'd have to extend `QueryReadStore` and override its `_fetchItems` method to customize the request further.

Comment: I have override the URL whenever I got inputs and its working fine.