# How to set DisplayField and ValueFiled of combobox

Tags: extjs

How to set DisplayField and ValueFiled of combobox with store response like ex: [1,2,3,4,5]

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
id: 'combo',
width: 400,
fieldLabel: 'distinct value',
emptyText: 'select',
store: '',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
renderTo:"viewFilter" ,
triggerAction: 'all',
editable: false,
pageSize:10,
});
```

store code

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    pageSize: 50,
    model: 'Model',
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'dynamicAjax.exc?action=getDistinctValues',
        simpleSortMode: true
    }
});
```

I am going to do lazy loading on combo box ,If you have any alternate solution just drive me.

Comment: What do you mean lazy loading? On what event would the `combobox` be loaded? To answer your original question, you set it exactly how you do: `displayField: 'name', valueField: 'id'`. What do you mean 'store response' [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, a store cannot work with a response of `[1,2,3,4,5]` out of the box.

You will have to convert the response to objects in the model. When you do that, you can set the field name to `text`, so you don't have to define the `displayField`.

I have made a working fiddle for you here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22k4

Comment: Do you have any example for lazy loading in ExtJS or Jquery without external library integration.

Comment: Lazy loading means first time the Combo box will be loaded with minimal amount of data after scroll or pagination it should load next level of data for ex: In 1000 data first it should load 50 data and next pagination or scroll it should next 50 data like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318256/search-in-combobox-with-pagination-extjs

Comment: can you please provide another example of it  since i am new to extjs

Comment: To be clear, my server returning 10000 line of data and i want it to populate in combo box but if i done this it will hang my page so that i want it to load as part by part.is any one have solution for it?